# Get customers latest order?

Tags: magento2

How on earth do I programatically retrieve customers latest order?

Tried a few solutions on the web, but they all get all orders from a customer, not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below code:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',your-customer-id)->setOrder('entity_id','DESC')->getFirstItem();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($order->getData());
```

**OR**

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',your-customer-id)->setOrder('created_at','DESC')->getFirstItem();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($order->getData());
```

Comment: Yep, only thing that worked, was getting the logged in users latest order. Any idea why the default didnt work and returned NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you an sql query for it which you can execute in your Magento 2 instance:

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_order` WHERE customer_id = 'your_customer_id' ORDER BY entity_id  DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the latest order of below code**

- First Create an order collection.
- The filter that Collection by Customer ID.
- Sort that collection by created_at desc. `setOrder('created_at', 'desc')`
- make the collection page size 0,1 by below code using `setPageSize(1),setCurPage(1)`

`

```
<?php

namespace {NameSpace};

class LastestOrder {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
   \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory    
    ) 
   {

        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    }
    public function getLastestOrder()
    {
        /**
         * \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $this->orderCollectionFactor
         */
        $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
        //Add all field to Collection
        $orders->addFieldToSelect('*');
        // Collection filter by Customer Id
        $orders->addFieldToSelect('customer_id',$customerId);
        // sort order by  create date descending
        $orders->setOrder('created_at','desc');
        // limit collection to 1
        $orders->setPageSize(1)->setCurPage(1);
        if($orders->count() > 0){
            $lastestOrder = $orders->getFirstItem();
            return $lastestOrder;
        }else{
            // no order found
            $lastestOrder = false;
        }

    }       
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get customer's last order and then any order info:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder;

public function __construct(
    OrderRepository $orderRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
}

/**
 * @param int $customerId
 * @return OrderSearchResultInterface
 */
public function getCustomerOrders(int $customerId): OrderSearchResultInterface
{
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(OrderInterface::CUSTOMER_ID, $customerId);
    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(OrderInterface::STATUS, ['canceled', 'holded'], 'nin');
    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $searchCriteria->setSortOrders(
        [
            $this->sortOrderBuilder
                ->setField(OrderInterface::CREATED_AT)
                ->setDirection(SortOrder::SORT_DESC)
                ->create()
        ]
    );
    $searchResults = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

    return $searchResults;
}

public function getLastOrder()
{
    $result = null;
    $searchResults = $this->getCustomerOrders(<customer_id_here>);

    if ($searchResults->getTotalCount() > 0) {
        $orders = $searchResults->getList();
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $lastOrder */
        $lastOrder = reset($orders);
        $result = $lastOrder;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Donot past same content to two different questions.it creates an auto-generate duplicate flag. Please change some content to avoid this issue.